# Installing Cellar on ServiceMix 7.0.0

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I have issue installing Cellar on Karaf ServiceMix 7.0.0

I followed the [Cellar documentation](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/cellar/latest-4/) the Cellar packages are built.

Installing th Cellar feature

```
karaf@root>feature:repo-add cellar
Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.karaf.cellar/apache-karaf-
cellar/LATEST/xml/features
karaf@root>feature:install cellar
Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=cellar; type=karaf.feature; version="[4.1.1,4.1.1]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=cellar)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=4.1.1)(version<=4.1.1))" [caused by: Unable to resolve cellar/4.1.1: missing requirement [cellar/4.1.1] karaf.cellar.provider [caused by: Unable to resolve cellar-hazelcast/4.1.1: missing requirement [cellar-hazelcast/4.1.1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.apache.karaf.cellar.utils; type=osgi.bundle; version="[4.1.1,4.1.1]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.karaf.cellar.utils/4.1.1: missing requirement [org.apache.karaf.cellar.utils/4.1.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.karaf.cellar.core)(version>=4.1.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))" [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.karaf.cellar.core/4.1.1: missing requirement [org.apache.karaf.cellar.core/4.1.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.karaf.features)(version>=4.1.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))"]]]]
```

I see plenty packages which are not resolved and as far I see the packages should be installed part of the feature

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as SMX 7.0.1 is based on Karaf 4.0.x, you have to use Cellar 4.0.x (not 4.1.x)

EDIT:

I have just installed it into fresh downloaded ServiceMix 7.0.1.

```
% sudo su
[sudo] password for bvn13:
co-ultraesb-test-01# mc

co-ultraesb-test-01# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
co-ultraesb-test-01# cd/opt
zsh: no such file or directory: cd/opt

co-ultraesb-test-01# ./bin/servicemix
Please wait while Apache ServiceMix is starting...
100% [========================================================================]
 ____                  _          __  __ _
/ ___|  ___ _ ____   _(_) ___ ___|  \/  (_)_  __
\___ \ / _ \ '__\ \ / / |/ __/ _ \ |\/| | \ \/ /
 ___) |  __/ |   \ V /| | (_|  __/ |  | | |>  <
|____/ \___|_|    \_/ |_|\___\___|_|  |_|_/_/\_\

  Apache ServiceMix (7.0.1)

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or 'system:shutdown' to shutdown ServiceMix.

karaf@root>feature:repo-add cellar 4.0.4
Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.karaf.cellar/apache-karaf-cellar/4.0.4/xml/features
karaf@root>feature:install cellar
karaf@root>
```

Comment: The Cellar 4.0.1 complained about the xmlns:nz prefix in the hazelcast XML, but that could be fixed quickly.